# ActionView::Template:Error(undefined method 'first_name' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My app seems to randomly be throwing an error when users are trying to load grid data into the form:

```
   ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass):
3:          t = @conts
4:                          xml.tag!("row",{ "id" => t.id }) do
5:
6:                                  xml.tag!("cell", t.first_name)
7:                                  xml.tag!("cell", t.last_name)
8:                          xml.tag!("cell", t.email)
9:                                  xml.tag!("cell", t.phone_1)
```

And following is the controller file

```
 def compdata
       @conts = Continfo.find_by_id(params[:id])
    end
```

Correspondence compdata RXML file

```
     xml.instruct! :xml, :version=>"1.0" 
       xml.tag!("rows") do
     t = @conts
        xml.tag!("row",{ "id" => t.id }) do

            xml.tag!("cell", t.first_name)
            xml.tag!("cell", t.last_name)
            xml.tag!("cell", t.email)
            xml.tag!("cell", t.phone_1)
            xml.tag!("cell", t.phone_2)
            xml.tag!("cell", t.homepage)
            xml.tag!("cell", t.skype)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## First item

It looks like  you have a few other similar questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667597/actionviewtempleteerrorundefined-method-each-for-nilnilclass) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163060/actioncontrollerroutingerroruninitialized-constant-adminscontroller)) open right now, and for both the current one and this one it looks like your `@conts` value is currently `nil` meaning nothing was brought back when it ran the search:

```
def compdata
  @conts = Continfo.find_by_id(params[:id])
end
```

Are you sure there is a value available in your table with the `id` equal to `params[:id]`?

If there is a mismatch there, that would be the first place I would look.

## Second item

You may also run into an issue trying to call the method `each` on `@conts` because the `find_by_id` method will **not** bring back an array. If you want it to iterate over each record instead of each key/val, try using `find_all_by_id` which will return an **array**.

## Third item

After looking at your other question, it looks like your syntax on this is different, but shouldn't you iterate over `@conts` again like this?

```
xml.tag!("rows") do
  @conts.each do |t|
    xml.tag!("row",{ "id" => t.id }) do
      xml.tag!("cell", t.first_name)
      xml.tag!("cell", t.last_name)
      xml.tag!("cell", t.email)
      xml.tag!("cell", t.phone_1)
      xml.tag!("cell", t.phone_2)
      xml.tag!("cell", t.homepage)
      xml.tag!("cell", t.skype)
    end
  end
end
```

This would be the way to assign `t` instead of like `t = @conts`, especially if you plan to step through many of them.

Comment: thanks a lot and happy new year.. we have values in our table for ID, but still we are not able to load the data from grid to form. we have to build our application like this with out using php, here is our link please go through it,and tell me how to link grid with form  to load the value to form,                   http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php? id=tutorials:dhtmlx_today:gridlink

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to do this with xml tags and all that? In rails, all of the forms and lists should be pre-built when you generate your scaffolding.